# Free Monte carlo simulator for financial quotes?

Tags: finance, montecarlo, quantitative-finance

I am experimenting with an application I am writing in prolog , and I need to use monte carlo simulator that would output prices for different randomly generated scenarios. Does anyone know where to look for something that would do this for free ? (I am not look for a library to use such as QuantLib)

Thanx

Comment: I don't see what could provide pricing and scenario generation but is totally unlike using a library such as QuantLib.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly what you are trying to do it is difficult to recommend something specific. However http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ has many monte carlo packages for R.

Personally I use http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monte-carlo/ which is a toolkit for haskell. I have not found the off the shelf simulators to be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are after a financial simulator in prolog, but if you are willing to use a different language I would try [R](http://www.r-project.org/).

For a brief taster, have a look at the following links:

- [R packages](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Finance.html) for financial applications.
- Applied finance with R [conference](http://www.rinfinance.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a research project that might interest you: http://www-rocq.inria.fr/mathfi/Premia/index.html.

It's free and covering the pricing of most financial derivatives, using various numerical methods..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you'll be able to utilize it for your use case, but we just open sourced our decently-performant command line Monte Carlo simulator. https://github.com/monetate/monte-carlo-simulator

It simply reads a csv on stdin and outputs a csv of all the random scenarios on stdout.